# What are the drawbacks and advantages to implementing namespacing with databases in Redis?

Tags: python, database, namespaces, redis, database-connection

Trying to organize our Redis keyspaces in a simple and (somewhat) extensible way, we've found an interesting mechanism: databases.  The idea would be to a name (say `person`, for example) to a database number, like `0`.  Then, all operations on the namespace `person` would go on the database `0`.

What are the drawbacks and advantages of doing this?  Is there a better way?

P.S.: We are using `Python 2.7`.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

Using multiple Redis databases is strongly discouraged.

Don't use it in production, **if** it's not a necessity (like when you're dealing with port range restrictions, hosted redis, and the likes).

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13386053/how-do-i-change-between-redis-database/21370126#21370126) post.

All of our redis instances have the following config parameter:

```
databases 1
```

How we deal with this, is the following:

We shard. We connect to a small redis instance first, which only contains connection strings. Given a context/environment, we connect to several redis instances. Most clients have 4 connections: 1 for the connection pool, 1 for read-only config settings, 1 for read of bulk data, 1 for write of bulk data. We put sentinels in between where appropriate.

We use Lua scripting to tie it all conveniently together. See this [diagram](http://tw-bert-doc.googlecode.com/hg/doc/doc_qxflux_fluxuri_boot-phase.swf) for a general gist.

Hope this helps, TW

Comment: Can you provide some reference as to _why_ it is strongly discouraged?  I found references for multiple databases not being supported for Redis *cluster*, but none for single-instance.

Comment: I already provided one, where I stated the reason. See above. Here is [another reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16221563/whats-the-point-of-multiple-redis-databases?rq=1).

Comment: One more: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16802090/use-multiple-dbs-with-one-redis-lua-script). Please note I said 'strongly discouraged'. It is not, nor are there plans to, deprecate multiple db's. It has been on the agenda for a short time, but decided against.